# How do I include MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN in the creation of a ClipData object?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an object draggable in an App ([following android developer's guide for this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html#DesignDragOperation)), and it looks like this:

```
ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag(), ClipData.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN, item);
```

But the IDE gives the following error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN'
```

So my question is this: How can I make the IDE recognize the MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN?

And yes, I've tried (what seems that should be the correct way) to change `ClipData.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN` to `ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN` but that just seems to make everything worse, like you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use type CharSequence for first and String array for second parameter.

```
ClipData dragData = new ClipData((CharSequence) v.getTag(), 
                                 new String[]{ ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN }, item);
```

Comment: Well, docs are still not fixed. Lost about 10 mins on this. Thanks!